# LabVIEW Front Panel Control Repositioning

Tags: labview

I have a problem repositioning controls on an existing LabVIEW 9.0 front panel. For some reason, they are offset down and to the right of the window, and I cannot simply select them and move them back up and to the left.  It's like there is some sort of invisible control in the top left corner that I can't see or get rid of.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you in edit mode (`Operate->change to edit mode`)? in this case you should scroll the front panel

Answer (score 1):

CharlesB makes a good suggestion.  Here are a couple others (apologies if they're too simplistic):

- Make sure you're in the dev environment, not a (non-modifiable) executable.
- ctrl-A or left-click and drag are alternative selection methods.  You should be able to shift everything that way.
- On the upper right hand icon, right click and select VI Properties.  Select Window Appearance, Customize... and make sure the scroll bars are enabled, so you can scroll more of the front panel onto the screen.
- Front panel corruption isn't unheard of.  Holding Ctrl-Shift and clicking the run arrow will force a recompile that may fix it.  If that fails, deleting and replacing the offending controls may help.

There are some more exotic solutions (using property nodes or scripting, for instance), but hopefully one of the above suggestions is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

They must have been grouped or locked:

> Grouping and Locking Objects
>
> Use the Positioning tool to select the
>   front panel objects you want to group
>   and lock together. Click the Reorder
>   button on the toolbar and select Group
>   or Lock from the pull-down menu.
>   Grouped objects maintain their
>   relative arrangement and size when you
>   use the Positioning tool to move and
>   resize them. Locked objects maintain
>   their location on the front panel and
>   you cannot delete them until you
>   unlock them. You can set objects to be
>   grouped and locked at the same time.
>   Tools other than the Positioning tool
>   work normally with grouped or locked
>   objects.

If you can post your VI (maybe after deleting all the block diagram code?), we can help better?

Answer (score 0):

The control might be an XControl, these controls (with embedded code) are hard to select, you can try to draw a rectangle (in edit mode) around the control and see if you can edit the VI.